# Добавленный контент оказывается снизу страницы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Сделал меню слева страницы, но добавляя остальной контент, он оказывается внизу.
Т.е. меню уже готово, я хочу начать добавлять контент  страницы, а он оказывается в самом низу. Пробовал `margin-bottom -500px;` - ничего не менялось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нам бы увидеть ваш код и скрин страницы, чтобы мы могли помочь. Сейчас мы ничего сделать не сможем

Comment: http://savepic.ru/15086069.png

Comment: @Theos, это по вашему код??)

Comment: И код пожалуйста. Теперь мы видим проблему, но не можем посмотреть из за чего она. Пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

для меню слева нужно задать `float: left;` а для контейнера, который будет вмещать контент, `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Супер. Помогло!
Спасибо!